# Which swap should I resize?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-management, swap

**elementaryOS** / Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

I recently upgraded memory on my computer to 8 GB and I feel like the swap I have is too big so I want to size it down. However, I noticed that there are 2 partitions on Disks application:

- `/dev/elementary-vg/swap_1`
- `/dev/mapper/cryptswap`

My memory was 6 GB and I only followed the guides that say to create swap twice your memory, but now I realized that both of these disks are 5.3 GB.

**TL;DR** I'm confused which to resize -- I might only need 2 GB swap or delete it completely.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, having the swap space twice the size of your RAM is only a guideline. Actually with 8 GB of physical RAM you won't need much swap space: you might want to keep the one and delete the other partition. If you want to use swap encryption you should keep the `cryptswap` if not, keep the other one.

However, **to hibernate you must have at least the same amount of swap *free* as you do RAM *used*.**